# Cannot import name find_packages?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweetstream

This is likely a rookie error, but im in the early stages of learning python.

- Running Win7 64bit
- Python is 2.7.2 64bit, python runs fine from CMD prompt.
- [I downloaded TweetStream.](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweetstream) and its under c:/
- Opened the setup.py in pyscripter.
- Executing it, I get this error:

[image]

Not too sure what I have done wrong, or how to rectify this problem.
Here is a [short screencast](http://screencast.com/t/CKaYjLHjdzpd) if it sheds anymore light.

EDIT - in response to comment.

```
c:\tweetstream-1.1.1>python setup.cfg install
  File "setup.cfg", line 2
    tag_build =
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: execute from a command-line: `python setup.py install` and paste the full traceback

Comment: setup. **py** is a Python script. setup. **cfg** is a configuration file. Look at the command in the previous comment more carefully.

Comment: my bad, rushed that without thinking.  It now installs, however I believe this was a result of me having to install setuptools as this was missing.  Let me know if you think im wrong.

Comment: missing setuptools is the most probable cause. The traceback would tell it for certain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Cookbook/AutoPackageDiscovery) can help you. Otherwise, you can install `setuptools` in your python, I don't think you have it installed. [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows)

Comment: I had the same issue, but in my case the version of setuptools was just too old. I uninstalled it via `pip uninstall setuptools` and reinstalled it. That helped

Answer (score 3):

I did the following and it worked for me:

`pip uninstall setuptools`

and then reinstall it:

`pip install setuptools`

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I uninstalled setuptools which was 62.0.3 then reinstalled it with 41.0.1, looks like I went backwards for unknown reasons

Comment: actually i got setuptools installed again, 62.0.3 which is the most update version but `find_packages` is still not working

Comment: I got it fixed.  I have to write `from setuptools import find_packages`, I was writing `import find_packages`